# Sysprep causing dual boot with different languages to become one

Tags: windows-10, sysprep

I'm an ICT coordinator in a secondary school where students can choose to be educated in either Dutch (native language) or English. Therefore I need to install W10 twice (dual boot): once in English, once in Dutch.

Everything works like it should, until I'm sysprepping my second (Dutch) install. It forces the first install (English) to become a copy of  the Dutch configuration. Hence all my work installing the English version is gone.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you just trying to say that Sysprep changes the default language of Dutch installation to English? It's not clear what you mean by "become a copy of Dutch configuration". If you are generalizing the image that's the normal behavior to remove all the machine and user specific configurations. You need to forget about setting a language in customization procedure, instead create an answer file with the language settings and apply it with sysprep.exe. If you need a more clear answer, please ask a more clear question that suggests what you exactly need to do.

Comment: For example you need to change system or user interface language, you need to add it as a keyboard layout or not and...

Comment: I need two different installs, in different languages. I need sysprep, but if I do that, the first complete sysprepped install is 'gone', since the settings of the second install overwrite everything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've got something wrong here, because Sysprep does not modify other installations. Instead, it may have changed the BCD GUID of both boot entries to the one of the second generalized installation/partition, like the one we see in [this thread](https://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/49005-dual-boot-win7-win8-1-sysprep-uefi-gpt-problem.html) (except for the fact that he dual booted windows 7 and 8.1, instead two windows 7s). Try to run a startup repair to fix the bootloaders for you. If it didn't work however, you can add them using "bcdedit" command line utility. Since both partitions are there and still intact, you just need to create or update the boot entry of first installation. In case you need me to clarify anything, please leave a comment and I'll update my answer with more details.